# Where can I find similar music to "Sogno di Volare" by Christopher Tin?

Tags: soundtrack, similar-artists

The song, below, is from the Civilization 6 soundtrack. I love the vocals and instrumentals and how perfectly he integrated them together.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1. Try [this YouTube mix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuS27il9LAs). The track list includes the names of the production companies/composers and the track title.
2. I found that video by searching YouTube for "[epic choral music](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=epic%20choral%20music)".
3. That search also brought up the classic "[O Fortuna](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXFSK0ogeg4)" from *Carmina Burana* by Karl Orff.
4. [Music-Map.com](https://www.music-map.com/) is a service I've had good luck with. Type in "[Christopher Tin](https://www.music-map.com/christopher+tin)", and it will suggest other musicians/bands/composers you might like.